# Multiple retrofit objects for different baseUrl and different SSLContext

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I am writing code to communicate with four different servers, and one of them need two different type of SSL.

I created a Retrofit object four times to get four interfaces with different baseURL. It's like...

```
InterfaceOne one = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("address1")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceOne.class);

InterfaceTwo two = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("address2")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceTwo.class);

InterfaceThree three = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("address3")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceThree.class);

InterfaceFour four = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("address4")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceFour.class);
```

For me it seems like repeating code. So my first question is, is this a good structure to handle four different baseURL?

And, I am going to use the structure like below for the server with two different SSL. But already it seems ugly for me.

```
OkHttpClient okhttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(getSSLContextOne().getSocketFactory())
            .build();

interfaceFour_1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okhttp)
            .baseUrl("address4")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceFour_1.class);

OkHttpClient okhttp2 = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(getSSLContextTwo().getSocketFactory())
            .build();

interfaceFour_2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okhttp2)
            .baseUrl("address4")
            .build()
            .create(InterfaceFour_2.class);
```

Is there any better way to improve current code?